# How to combine IF formula with IMSUB

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to make it so that if the answer to imsub=0 the if formula turns the 0 into a blank (""). What formula would I use to accomplish this? Right now I have come up with =IF(IMSUB(A1,A2)=0,"",(IMSUB(A1,A2)))
So if A1 is 10 and A2 is 10 then I want the answer to be blank.
But if A1 is 10 and A2 is 8 I want the answer to be 2.

Answer (score 0):

You have to split you answer into step cell process. If you want a single answer then you have to VBA macro coding functions plugins.

Comment: How would I do both step cell process and vba macro coding? what would I put for the macro plugins? Thanks